# Show a graph with maximum degree 5 $(\Delta(G) =5 )$ is 2 colorable with components as paths or cycles for every color

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree 5 $(\Delta(G) =5 )$ Then there exists a coloring of $G$ in two colors(not necessarily proper) such that each connected component of the subgraphs induced by those colors is a path or a cycle

I already know $\chi(G)\leq \Delta(G)+1=6$, so I figured I'd take a 6 coloring of $G$ and merge color classes $1,2,3$ and $4,5,6$. That is a 2 coloring of $G$ in colors 1 and 2 respectively, but I don't know that each connected component of all the vertices of the same color is a path or a cycle, so that lead me to thinking this might not be true, However I can't think of a counter example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the $2$-coloring which maximizes the number of edges with opposite-color endpoints.

Then each vertex $v$ has at most two neighbors of the same color. If $v$ had three neighbors of the same color, it would have at most two neighbors of the *opposite* color, and you could increase the number of edges with opposite-color endpoints by switching the color of $v$.

It follows that the subgraph induced by each color has maximum degree $2$, so each subgraph is the union of paths and cycles.